# What is the benefit of using OpenGL fan instead of creating a circle based on varying position?

Tags: c++, opengl, geometry, drawing, shader

All opengl tutorials I've seen that show how to create a circle in OpenGL use the "Fan" method (or some derivative), and I've not seen one use the following method:

Create a set of vertices like so:

```
float vertices[] = {
            0.5f,  0.5f, 0.0f,  1.0f,  1.0f, // top right
            0.5f, -0.5f, 0.0f,  1.0f, -1.0f, // bottom right
            -0.5f, -0.5f, 0.0f, -1.0f, -1.0f,// bottom left
            -0.5f,  0.5f, 0.0f,  -1.0f,  1.0f// top left
};
```

Create the following Vertex Shader which passes out the bounds information in varying format to fragment shader:

```
#version 330 core

in vec3 apos;
in vec2 abound;

out vec3 ourColor;
out vec2 ourBound;

void main() {
    gl_Position = vec4(apos, 1.0);
    ourBound = abound;
}
```

Create the following fragment shader which takes the interpolated bounds values to figure out the current fragment distance from center

```
#version 330 core

in vec2 ourBound;

uniform vec4 setColor;

void main() {
    float dist = sqrt((ourBound.x * ourBound.x) + (ourBound.y * ourBound.y));
    vec4 color_used = vec4(vec3(1.0), 0.0);
    if(dist < 1.0){
        color_used = setColor;
    }
    gl_FragColor = color_used;
}
```

- Load Shaders
- Enable Blending
- Initialize VBO/EBO objects for apos (offset = 0, stride = 5 * sizeof(float)) and for abound (offset = 3, stride = 5 * sizeof(float))
- Intialize colorLocation
- Store in VBA

in draw loop load program:

```
    glClearColor(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f);
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
    glUseProgram(shader_program);
    glUniform4f(colorLocation, 0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f);
    glBindVertexArray(VAO);
    glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLES, 6, GL_UNSIGNED_INT, 0);
    glBindVertexArray(0);
```

My result 
[image]

I don't understand the benefit for creating a fan instead.  Is there some performance benefit? It certainly doesn't seem to be simpler.  I simply cannot find alternative solutions via google besides the one here.

Comment: What happens if you don't have access to the programmable pipeline and can't do per-pixel `incircle()` checks?

Comment: @genpfault what do you mean?  In what situation would this be the case and still conform with an non-ancient OpenGL standard, especially 3.3+ core?  That would imply you couldn't even make shaders.  This fan pattern seems to be taught regardless of the opengl version any way.

Comment: If you don't have shaders you *can't* do the `incircle()` trick.  The triangle fan method works with both the fixed-function and programmable pipelines.

Comment: @genpfault Its not a "trick"... what device would you could make a shader, but couldn't use a varying? Also, there is no "incircle()" function, I thought you were just referring to the if statement earlier (which can be trivially transformed into a clamp with out branching), but your diction implies otherwise.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> I don't understand the benefit for creating a fan instead.

It's a *tutorial*. The purpose of a tutorial is to teach some particular skill, not necessarily to present the best way to do something. What matters in a tutorial is not necessarily the outcome, but the way you achieve it.

The two ways of creating a circle require vastly different skills. The vertex method involves using `sin`/`cos` to compute points on the edge of a circle, as well as how to upload such data into a buffer and use that buffer to render with. Your impostor method demonstrates how to create 2D impostors, and how to tell if a point is inside of a (unit) circle.

A person who knows how to do point-in-circle does not know how to use `sin` and `cos` to compute the points on a circle. As such, if you then move on to doing spheres, you have to teach them about `sin` and `cos`. Whereas if you did circles via vertices before, then they're one step ahead and can learn about spherical coordinate systems as an extension of what they already know.

Furthermore, the vertex method is an easy way to teach users that more vertices can create smoother results. It also helps them learn that this is resolution-dependent; the farther you are from the vertex-based circle, the less the number of vertices matter. You can even use this to teach people how to do dynamic LODing, where you recompute the vertices every frame. This involves streaming data to buffer objects dynamically.

It doesn't matter if you would never use dynamic LODs for a mere circle. What matters is that the user has learned how to do buffer streaming.

These are two different sets of skills. Both sets are meaningful and useful, but they are *different*. There is nothing intrinsically wrong with either method; it's all a matter of what skills you're trying to teach.

> It certainly doesn't seem to be simpler.

It depends on how you define "simpler". If the tutorial is trying to teach a user to understand triangle rendering, then your impostor-based approach is not simpler. It's also not teaching *triangle rendering*.

Your way requires that the user have a formal understanding of what's going on at the fragment level. And don't get me wrong; that's a *good thing*. Teaching users how to make impostors is a very good tool. But is that the tool that the user is ready to learn at that point in their development?

Furthermore, the shader approach is more limited. Let's say you want to add textures to this circle. With the vertex approach, you do the normal thing: add texture coordinates to the vertices, pass them along to the fragment shader, and let it fetch from the texture. With the shader approach, the FS has to invent the specific mapping from the texture to the circle.

This means that any time you want to change this mapping, you must change your FS. You can add some parameters to the FS to support variations of scaled mapping, but even this means you now have to break up your triangle batches in order to change the mapping parameters. Whereas with the vertex approach, you can render any number of fans in a single draw call (thanks to vertex restarting), just by baking the mapping into the vertex data.

Indeed, with the vertex approach, you can use the exact same shader for your circles as you do for any other shape. The shader approach requires changing shaders just to render something different.

Personally, I think tutorials should teach impostor methods earlier than they do. But I don't think circle impostors are the best way to go.

> Is there some performance benefit?

Well, there is if you look at it from an antialiasing perspective. Your fragment-based method would need special coding to work with multisampling. To do it properly, you would need to compute the distance for each sample position, then output a sample mask corresponding with that. Or invoke per-sample shading. Either way, this will be a bit slower.

But that would make for an interesting lesson.

Comment: +1 for actually answering the question :)   The multisampling idea also makes sense, wouldn't have thought about that (I come from a CUDA/OpenCL background, and OpenGL kind of frustrates me with how limiting it is compared what I know the GPU can do)  If I had access to the proper compute utilities this wouldn't me an issue, but in OpenGL I don't think dealing with this would be trivial.

Comment: @snb: What wouldn't be an issue? Multisampling is a by-product of triangle rasterization; you can't directly invoke it with "proper compute utilities". And fragment shaders give you all the tools you need to set the sample mask; it just won't be *free*, since you'll still need to do the computation for each sample.

Comment: @snb: "*I come from a CUDA/OpenCL background*" That actually makes the vertex method *more* important for you. Your natural instincts will be to "solve it in a shader," since that's what you know best. If you want to learn graphics, you need to set aside such instincts. Yes, the graphics pipeline includes shaders, but it also includes *more* than that, and a good graphics programmer needs to know how to use all of the available tools. Because even if an imposter is the better solution in this case, that doesn't make it the right answer generally.

Comment: @snb: I've added a few more useful features of the vertex method.

Comment: @snb: "*You can implement OpenGL itself in CUDA if you wanted*" Only if you want your rendering to be really slow. CUDA doesn't have access to the hardware rasterizer or many other aspects of the graphics pipeline. So that means no hardware-based Hi-Z depth culling and so forth. Also, GLSL gives you "a location that actually corresponds with a pixel screen coordinate"; it's called `gl_FragCoord`.

Comment: I don't really see how some one could make a better answer at this point, so I'm accepting this one.

Answer (score 0):

> Is there some performance benefit?

In your version a vertex fan might be better but if you change the fragment shader in the following way it should be equally fast.

```
#version 330 core

in vec2 ourBound;

uniform vec4 setColor;

void main() {
    //no sqrt required
    float dist = dot(ourBound,ourBound);

    //discard pixels on the outside.
    //We can leave blending disabled.
    if(dist > 1.0){
        discard;
    }
    vec4 color_used = vec4(vec3(1.0), 0.0);
    gl_FragColor = color_used;
}
```

> I don't understand the benefit for creating a fan instead.

If you just want to display a 2D circle i don't think there is a benefit.

**Alternative way:**

Since it seems like you want to display a simple 2D circle you could render quad and put a texture with alpha channel on it. With that it is easy to get a very nice anti-aliased circle or any other 2D object.

Comment: the issue with the texture method is that it wouldn't scale, if I change the location/scale of my quad my circle maintains its dimensions (provided the quad is still square, which also means easy elispis when it isn't) and doesn't lose any information or have any aliasing artifacts like a texture would.

Comment: Also thanks for the info on `dot` didn't even cross my mind glsl might have that.